# Solution for wave equation (infinite string, external force)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, wave-equation

I am a novice in PDE, and I met a problem, I reduced it to

$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=f(x,t), -\infty <x<+\infty,t>0 \\
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x), -\infty<x<+\infty \\
u_{t}(x,0)=u_{1}(x),-\infty<x<+\infty
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly if $f=0$, the solution would be the D'Alembert Formula. So can anyone solve this problem for me?

Also, I am looking for a pde book that is full of solutions for wave equation with different boundary condition, so... any recommendations?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Solving this for a generic function $f(x,t)$ (and generic boundary conditions) is a little bit ambitious...

Comment: @the_candyman yeah I know, but we found the solutions of wave equation with numerous boundary conditions, right?

Comment: I mean, in every solution, we find a way to set a new variable, and somehow they satisfy all the conditions

Comment: [This](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Applied-Partial-Differential-Equations/dp/1429275928/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510765188&sr=8-1&keywords=john+davis+partial+differential+equations&dpID=51p4ovvCnsL&preST=_SX218_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch) has lots of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\begin{cases}p=x+t\\q=x-t\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_x=u_pp_x+u_qq_x=u_p+u_q$

$u_{xx}=(u_p+u_q)_x=(u_p+u_q)_pp_x+(u_p+u_q)_qq_x=u_{pp}+u_{pq}+u_{pq}+u_{qq}=u_{pp}+2u_{pq}+u_{qq}$

$u_t=u_pp_t+u_qq_t=u_p-u_q$

$u_{tt}=(u_p-u_q)_t=(u_p-u_q)_pp_t+(u_p-u_q)_qq_t=u_{pp}-u_{pq}-u_{pq}+u_{qq}=u_{pp}-2u_{pq}+u_{qq}$

$\therefore u_{pp}-2u_{pq}+u_{qq}-(u_{pp}+2u_{pq}+u_{qq})=f\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2},\dfrac{p-q}{2}\right)$

$-4u_{pq}=f\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2},\dfrac{p-q}{2}\right)$

$u_{pq}=-\dfrac{1}{4}f\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2},\dfrac{p-q}{2}\right)$

$u(p,q)=F(p)+G(q)-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^q\int_0^pf\left(\dfrac{r+s}{2},\dfrac{r-s}{2}\right)~dr~ds$

$u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_0^{x-t}\int_0^{x+t}f\left(\dfrac{r+s}{2},\dfrac{r-s}{2}\right)~dr~ds$

Comment: Duplicate answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2512257/44121 .